# Why does clicking on one form element set focus to another?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a strange problem. When I click on my form's 'TransDesc' input text element, focus goes immediately to the first element, 'Quantity'. I believe it has something to do with my onchange for the 'Amount' element.

In order to get focus in 'TransDesc', I have to tab past 'Quantity' and then 'Amount'.

I tried a set focus in retTotalAmt(), but that did not work.

What do I need to change, so I can click on TransDesc, and not have the focus return to 'Quantity'

```
function retTotalAmt()
{
var total_amt = 
document.forms["InvGenPayTickets"]["Quantity"].value * ticketCost;

document.getElementById('Amount').value = total_amt.toFixed(2);
}

.
.
.

Quantity
<input type='text' name='Quantity' id='Quantity' 
       onchange="return retTotalAmt();" /> 

Amount 
$<input type='text' name='Amount' id='Amount' readonly="readonly" />
<input type=text name="TransDesc" id="TransDesc" maxlength=255 />
```

There are  elements surrounding some of the form fields.

Comment: do you have `<label>` elements surrounding input fields in the form?

Comment: Yes, I do. Do I need to remove them all, or just the one getting the focus?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle example?

Comment: no I think there are some conflict with ID's to which labels are referencing

Comment: I am talking about situation like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/W7LQR/), click on the second input

Comment: Please answer my question with label. Removing that fixed things, and did not ruin the look of my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think there is a problem with `<label>` elements surrounding input fields, probably there are confusing IDs like in this example:

```
<label for="input1"><input id="input1" /></label>
<label for="input1"><input id="input2" /></label>​
```

so if you don't need that labels, just remove them or try to fix the IDs